# Add multiple classes to dom element one by one js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add 2 classes to my div with an event listener, but I want it to add one list, update the DOM, and add the second class

I need to move the div with the id app to the top and then to the left when the user clicks the key `1`, but it goes up and left at the same time.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-image: url("TPHRG floorplan1.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        /* background-position: center; */
        background-size: 980px 400px, cover;
      }

      .robot_start_top {
        top: 280px;
        transition: top 1s;
      }

      .robot_start_left {
        position: fixed;
        left: 600px;
        transition: all 1s;
      }

      .robot_end_left {
        left: 500px;
      }

      .robot_end_top {
        top: 180px;
      }

      .robot1_start_left {
        position: fixed;
        left: 600px;
        transition: left 1s;
      }

      .robot1_end_left {
        left: 400px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onkeydown="move(event)">
    <div class="robot_start_left robot_start_top" id="app">
      <img id="robot" style="width:30px; height:40px" />
    </div>

    <script>
      let count = 0;
      var move = function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 97) {
          const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
          setTimeout(function() {
            appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
          }, 0);
          setTimeout(function() {
            appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_left");
          }, 0);
        }

        if (event.keyCode === 98) {
          const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
          appDiv.classList.add("robot1_end_left");
        }
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

but in this way, it adds all 2 classes at once.

Here is the whole code in **[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-v2f46?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)**

Comment: have you tried to add timeout

Comment: @StefanAvramovic yeah, it doesn't helped

Comment: @RobertHovhannisyan how **exactly** did the version with the timeout look?

Comment: What exactly are you waiting for? What do you mean "update the DOM"? There is no code changing the DOM here. Are you waiting some amount of seconds? For an animation to complete?

Comment: Also there's no reason to use an external site for code demonstrations. Stack Overflow supports such facilities directly.

Comment: @matthew-e-brown I suspect that the OP wants to see the visible result of adding the first class and only then the result of adding the second class.

Comment: like this : `setTimeout(() => appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top"))` and the same for the second class

Comment: You have to pass a numeric second argument to `setTimeout()`, indicating the number of milliseconds to wait.

Comment: setTimeout(function(){ appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_left"); }, 3000);

Comment: @matthew-e-brown do you see the div with the id app, I want to move it to the top and then left when the user clicks the key `1`, but with the code above it moves top and left at the same time.

Comment: @Pointy Thank you for your attention, I made an edit

Comment: Why are you passing 0 to `setTimeout()`? Maybe pass 0 to the first one but then 500 or 1000 to the second.

Comment: @Pointy I just tried it and it helps. Thank you very much! Please, can you summarize it with the answer, I want to appreciate you somehow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers will generally let JavaScript code like yours do a burst of DOM updates without doing anything visually. They'll wait until the script exits (like an event handler) or until something in the script requires that the browser do the visual update before it can provide an answer.

In your case, the simplest thing to do is defer the addition of the "second" class for some fractions of a second; exactly how long depends on what you want it to look like. The way you'd do that would be something like

```
  setTimeout(() => { appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_left") }, 500);
```

That 500 means to wait 500 milliseconds before adding the second class.